# How to remove low values from a tsv file

Tags: python

I have this TSV file:

```
    kind        10
    men        9
    number        8
    animated        7
    blade        6
    jolly        5
    manage        4
    move         3
    complete        2
    meat        1
```

And I would like to remove all words which have less than the number 5 next to them.

So only :

```
    Output: 
    kind        10
    men        9
    number        8
    animated        7
    blade        6
    jolly        5
```

I would like to do this as python code. I was thinking maybe I could load it in a list and from there look at the number, and if it's less than 5 it's removed. But how to do that I'm not sure.

Something like this:

```
    new_file = open(the_file,encoding="utf-8")
    data = new_file.readlines()
    new_list = []
    for values in data:
        if values > 5:
            new_list.append(values)
```

Comment: you should consider using [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for parsing (c/t)sv files, for tsv use: `csv.reader(new_file, delimiter="\t") `. If you are not sure how to proceed it always helps to use `print()` to see what is the value in the variable you are dealing with. Then you could see you have a list there instead of number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community.
As others have suggested, you may very well use pandas. If you want to use the csv module, you can do something like the following:

```
import csv

tsv_file = open("example.tsv")
read_tsv = list(csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t"))

for row in read_tsv:
    if float(row[1]) < 5:
        read_tsv.remove(row)
```

That reads the file into a list of lists, each row being one list. If the value its always gonna be the second one, you can read it like that and eliminate the row from the bigger list. Hope it helped!

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry, I just saw your comment. Try something else like what I edited up in this post (I did a couple of assumptions about CSV Reader that were wrong, but I think that it is fixed now. Hope it works.

Comment: Hello, I tried this method, but when I print the file, it gives me "AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'drop'"

Comment: Maybe I have to import something, other than csv, to use the drop attribute

Comment: Edited! Sorry for the hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at this kind of files I would really look into Pandas. That's basically Excel on steroids.

The code would look more or less like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t')
df = df.loc[4 < df['column_name']]
```

Comment: isnt Pandas a bit overkill for something what can be handled with builtin `csv` module?

Comment: In a way, yes. But if the TS is interested in working with this kind of data and Python it's just so powerful. And the documentation and resources available are great. I can't tell of course what the ultimate aim of the TS is, I see you suggested the csv module as well so let's see where he or she wants to take it :)

Comment: Beware Pandas is not Python. It is a large framework *supported* from Python but having quite different semantics. For any *standard* Python object `a`, after `b = a`, `b == a` is the boolean `True`. So you can safely do `if b == a: # do_something`. But not with Pandas objects...

Comment: Sure it's powerful, but considering OP is struggling with basic data filtering (not meant as an offense, everyone starts at some point), I dont think they're ready to be thrown into deep water of Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read in the file. This will give you a list with each line from the file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'rt') as file:
    content = file.readlines()
```

Now its enough to check the integer made from the last to digits of each line (after stripping the newline character). Compare it to 5 and then write it back to the file, like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'wt') as file:
    file.writelines([c for c in content if int(c.strip()[-2:]) >= 5])
```

Comment: I tried this as well, however it doesn't change anything in my tsv file, it's still the same amount of data points left.

Comment: Did you replace `test.txt` with your file?

Comment: Yes I did, the actual file I want to run has 55 804 points of data, but it's all tsv. After I run the code I use the len operator to see the length of the file and its still 55 804.

Comment: Hmm, it was working for me fine with your example tsv file. You only have those two columns, right?

Comment: Yes, only those two columns, one for the word and the other for the number. Its word first and then next to the word is the number separated by a TAB between them.

Comment: Okay nevermind, I guess the other answers work fine, so no need to push this.